# Shouldn't l'Hopital's rule work for every limit, not just indeterminate forms?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Why does taking the ratio of $f'(x)$ to $g'(x)$ as $x \to a$ give you the correct limit when $f(a)$ and $g(a)$ $= 0, \infty, -\infty$  , but not for other values of $a$?

If the rationale for using LHR is that the tangent is the linear approximation of the curve at a point, shouldn't the rule work for all values of $a$?

Comment: Explain more why you think that it has to be true... You will notice that there are a little issues on your think... Did you try to see the proof of the theorem? It reveals several technical details that  you must take to work

Comment: I think the best way to understand a theorem is to understand it's proof. Because the proof gievs you the entire path from the hypotheses to the conclusion. Unless you traverse the full path the link between hypotheses and conclusion remains a mystery. A proof of LHopital shows where the hypotheses $f(a)=g(a)=0$ is used and why it is vital to the conclusion.

Comment: Another approach which relies on geometric intuition is to look at curve $y=f(t),x=g(t)$ which passes through origin. The slope of curve at origin is $\lim_{t \to 0}f(t)/g(t)$. The slope of curve in general is $dy/dx = f'(t)/g'(t)$. Intuition demands that as $t \to 0$ the tangent at $t$ will approach the tangent at origin. Hence as $t \to 0$ the slope $f'(t)/g'(t)$ also tends to the slope of tangent at origin which is $\lim_{t \to 0}f(t)/g(t)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe we should look at why L'Hopital's rule works when it does.  This might not be the most rigorous explanation but it should give you the idea.

$\lim\limits_{a\to x} f(a)/g(a) = \lim\limits_{h\to 0} f(x+h)/g(x+h)$

when h is small $f(x+h)$~$f(x) + f'(x)h$

$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}f(x+h)/g(x+h) = \dfrac {f(x) + f'(x)h}{g(x) + g'(x)h}$

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both $0$, then that limit equals $f'(x)/g'(x)$

If either $f(x)$ or $g(x)$ are not $0$.  Then the limit equals $f(x) / g(x)$

Lets throw some numbers in there... suppose $f(x) = 0, f'(x) = 1, g(x) =1 , g'(x) = -1$

$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}f(x+h)/g(x+h) = \dfrac {h}{1-h}$
what happens when h goes to 0?

Comment: I think I understand the use of the differential $f'(x)h$ in your first line and the rest of your argument as to why it works when they're both zero, but I don't understand your last line. Do you mean trivially small relative to $f(x)$ and $g(x)$?

Comment: I will edit my post and add more detail

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate. I've actually been reading about it over and over in my book, but I can't figure out that part at all...

Comment: Ah....got it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A limit is when tending to a *single* final value. L'Hopital's Rule is for comparing *two* limits that seem to tend to limits easily determinable individually but not when taken divisively together. They are indeterminate in a comparison before the Rule is differentially applied.